# How to put an external antenna on a wireless card

Tags: usb, wireless, antenna, wire, usb-device

I have a USB wireless card and the listing said the following (If any use) "Mini 150Mbps USB WiFi Wireless Adapter Network LAN Card 802.11n/g/b 2.4GHz".

[image]

I am wondering how I could put an external Antenna (like the picture below) on this card or a similar one. Can I just solder leads to the Antenna and then to the board?

EDIT: I have looked inside of it, you can solder on to the internal contacts, My question is will the wire from the antenna to the new antenna still transfer the "signal" through it or do I need special wire.

[image: http://www.mouser.com/images/digiinternational/lrg/inhouse_a24hasm450_2.jpg]

Comment: Have you actually looked inside that thing? Do you have a scanning electron microscope and a very steady hand...?

Comment: It has 2 copper Tabs in it (I assume for the radio) that are about 3mmx3mm. I believe that can be soldered on.

Comment: You could do that, but you have to make sure that your external antenna and the one your card uses have the same impedance, which is unlikely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, Yes you can, BUT you have to bypass the resistors going to the old antenna in order to get the full potential from it.

Comment: But the new antenna will inevitably have a completely different impedance / gain characteristics thus quite possibly damaging the output amp on the chipset.  RF is a mysterious art and you can't just whack an antenna on something and expect it to work.  I wish it was that simple. :)

Comment: @Wossname me too :/